# How to apply setter value to computed property vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have computed property

```
 rwprice: {
      get() {
        return this.type == 'desc' ? 0 : this.sell_max
      },
      set(val) {
        return val
      }
    },
```

How to create sette for this property? What i can use, some like  `this.rwprice = 25`?

Comment: A computed value is not meant to be assigned a value. Why are you trying to manually set the value of a computed property?

Comment: A setter doesn't return a value; here you `return val;` which is wrong. A setter should SET a value; ie `this.sell_max = val;`